# scp - Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: scp

Trying to copy files over from serverB to serverA and get the following error:

```
root@server:~# scp /root/test.txt root@111.111.111.111:/home/somefolder/
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

On serverA I created a public/private key pair with no passphrase.
On serverB I added the public key to the .ssh/authorized_keys file.  Both the folder and file is owned by root.

I originally tried this with a passphrase... since it was not working I created another key without a passphrase.  Both are giving the same results.

This is not a firewall issue.
serverA is centos.
serverB is ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same problem. Hope this will work for you.

`scp -rp -i yourfile.pem ~/local_directory username@instance_url:directory`

Permission should also be correct to make this work.

Answer (score 6):

Run scp with verbose mode (-vvv) and see if you can identify the problem there. It could be the permissions on your .ssh/authorized_key file on the destination (or even the source) are too open.

Comment: Verbose mode helped me realize that I'd copied the command from Windows and left the file separator as a backslash

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I needed to specify the identity in the scp command something like so :

```
scp -rp -i /root/.ssh/server /home/user-data/* root@111.111.111.111:/home/user-data
```

where '/root/.ssh/server' is the location of the private key to be used.  Permissions and ownership should be correct for it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I ran into with this was the user account was locked.  A bang (exclamation point character) was in the /etc/shadow password field which meant the account was locked.  To fix it, I had to

```
sudo vi /etc/shadow
```

And change the '!!' to '*'.  Alternatively, you could set a password for the account

```
sudo passwd newacct
```

See also [What does * mean in passwd file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219260/what-does-star-in-passwd-file-mean)

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in `/var/log/secure` file? Probably `.ssh/*` have bad permissions.

So you can try to run `ssh -v` command to see what's the problem.